# How do I autoresize and rearrange DIVs with a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, autoresize

I am working on a project of mine and I've always wanted to incorporate a feature where the 
div's on my home page would resize and rearrange automatically (as I resize the browser). Now I know HTML and CSS but not much of any of the other language to make this happen.

What I am talking about is here http://themes.elmastudio.de/renkon/ (try resizing the browser).

Can you please explain how this works or at least refer me to a website where I can learn more, even a tutorial?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: try bootstrap (just Google it). Lots of info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site you referenced is using a JavaScript library called Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/.  They provide some intro documentation on how to use the library here: http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html.  If you need help getting started with JavaScript and jQuery, I recommend the W3Schools tutorials.